Fedora latex doc packages
There is the dnf package latex-scheme-full, which I have installed (using Fedora 40). However, running texdoc [some installed package] rarely yields anything useful; which I attribute to the various latex documentation packages dnf provides not being installed. There seems to be no latex-scheme-full-doc-package. How can I get the latex docs through dnf?

Instead of using the linux packages, you could install vanilla texlive from tug.org. This will allow you to do a full install with all the packages, docs and sources. This will also allow you to get faster updates.
